# Scale texture at runtime in unity

Tags: unity, c#, textures, scale

I need to scale the texture in unity3d.In unity we are able to adjust the scale using the option in the toolbar
[image]

How will I scale the texture at runtime using the mouse pointer.

the texture should scale when i click and drag on the any four corners of the image as shown in the below image

[image]

Can anybody please help me in solving this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Zoom in? or just scale up/down?

Comment: Scale the image when we drag the corner points of the image

Comment: You'd use 4 empty gameobjects with colliders attached. Then using Raycast2D, identify if mouse is on one of them, then detect how far the mouse is moving and set the scale in update accordingly.

Comment: @SanSolo : can you please provide me with the sample code

Comment: I don't have the code ready. It's one of those things that though simple requires quite a few lines of code. However, i found an answer that uses Raycasting just like i mentioned. Check it out :) http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/301951/how-can-i-make-a-gameobject-scaleresize-with-mouse.html